# Checkbox binding in Google AppMaker

Tags: data-binding, google-apps-script, google-app-maker

How to do binding for the checkbox? together with the user input if they choose other here? can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Provide html code, I think u use js to do it but I can't help without html code

Comment: how to do it if has HTML code?

Comment: `use js to do it`

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Bind to what? What is your data model? Can you update the Q with more details? Like should user be able to select multiple, should checkboxes clear if user selects `other` etc...

Comment: Bind to "TabletUsed" in my data field. Of course user can select multiple if it is a checkbox. And if it is user input then bind that input also to data model of field "TabletUsed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest implementation will be with [Multiselect Widget](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/input-widgets#multi-select). However, it will look slightly different:

**Model**

[image: Model]

**Designer**

Note, [strToArray](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/transformers#strToArray) transformer is used in the `values` binding

[image: Designer]

**Runtime**

[image: Runtime]

For sure, you can go fancy customizing look and feel of the Multiselect with CSS or playing with input's visibility basing on selected values and so on...